# Unknown authentication strategy: hapi-auth-bearer-simple

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to use hapi-auth-bearer-simple module to enable bearer token on my app. However, I am getting the error shown in the title.

I am trying to implement this module to enable token authorisation in my app But I am getting error mentioned below

`e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:723`

I have a route file

```
module.exports = [
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/{_id?}',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
           Controller.control.get(request.params, function (err, success) {
                console.log(request.params);
                if (err) {  
                    reply(unifunc.sendError(err));
                } else {
                    reply(unifunc.sendSuccess(SuccessMsg,success)).code(200);
                }
            });
        },
        config: {
            description: 'desc',
            tags: ['api', 'oV'],
            validate: {
                headers: unifunc.authorizationHeaderObj,
                params: {
                    o_id: Joi.string().required().trim(),
                    _id: Joi.string().optional().trim()
                },
                failAction: unifunc.failActionFunction
            },
            auth: {
                strategy: 'bearer',
                scope: ['admin', 'user-{params.id}']
                },
            plugins: {
                'hapi-swagger': {
                    responseMessages: msgs
                }](url)
```

and a controller file in which I mentioned strategy

```
var bearerSimple= require('hapi-auth-bearer-simple')
authorization = Authorization.auth; // This plugin has the logic to validate the token and return the error in case it fails and I am passing accesstoken as parameter in a function in that file
var getV = function(server, params, callbackRoute){  
    server.register(
        [{
            register: bearerSimple
        }], function(err){
     if(err){
         console.log("Failed to log the plugin",err);
         throw err;
     }
     server.auth.strategy('bearer', 'bearerAuth', {
        authorization : authorization
     });
    });
    console.log(params);
    async.series([
        function(cb){}
        ]}
```

complete error message is:

```
Error: Unknown authentication strategy: bearer in path: /api/orders/{order_id}/vehicles/{_id?}
    at Object.exports.assert (e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\hoek\lib\index.js:723:11)
    at e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\hapi\lib\auth.js:152:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at internals.Auth._setupRoute (e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\hapi\lib\auth.js:149:24)
    at new module.exports.internals.Route (e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\hapi\lib\route.js:142:47)
    at internals.Connection._addRoute (e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\hapi\lib\connection.js:375:17)
    at internals.Connection._route (e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\hapi\lib\connection.js:367:18)
    at wrappedRoute [as _route] (e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\newrelic\lib\instrumentation\hapi.js:222:29)
    at internals.Plugin._apply (e:\python_training\Training\Node\Test\Project\Backend\node_modules\hapi\lib\plugin.js:460:14)
    at internals.Plugin.route
```

Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Edit:
I modified server.js file and removed the strategy from controller file

I placed strategy in server.js

```
var validationFunction = Authorization.auth;
console.log(validationFunction);

server.register(
    [{
        register: bearerSimple
    }], function(err){
 if(err){
     console.log("Failed to log the plugin",err);
     throw err;
 }

 server.auth.strategy('bearer', 'bearerAuth', {
    validationFunction : validationFunction
 });
});
```

and in Authorization file looks like this

```
function rauth(accessToken, cb) {
    var criteria = {accessToken: accessToken};
    var projection = {};
    var options = {limit: 1};
    Service.AdminService.getadmin(criteria, projection, options, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
        } else if (data && data.length > 0 && data[0]._id) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.length);
            adminId = data[0]._id;
            cb()
        } else {
            cb(UniversalFunctions.CONFIG.APP_CONSTANTS.STATUS_MSG.ERROR.INVALID_ACCESS_TOKEN);
        }
    });
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
Error: options.validateFunc must be a valid function in bearerAuthentication scheme
```

I have been breaking my head over this problem from days. Could anyone suggest what could be the problem here?

The only problem I found was with the parameters of callback function passed in validateFunction but I can't remove the parameters as those parameters are being defined in another function called getadmin. Could anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: There's a typo in your auth function `function rauth(accessToken, cb)` or is that just a pasting error?

Comment: it's a typo error! I found the issue it was with the function mentioned in the strategy. I mentioned validationFunction : validationFunction but it was supposed to be validateFunction : validationFunction. Although now when I run get method it doesn't even read the function created for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in this issue https://github.com/Salesflare/hapi-auth-bearer-simple/issues/69.
The problems were a typo and needed to pass more info back on a successful authorization.